# How to connect to pymongo with django

Tags: django, mongodb, ssh, python-3.6, pymongo

my DB connection is

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'djongo',
            'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': True,
            'NAME': 'taxiapp',
            'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': xxxx,
        }
    }
```

my `SSH ADDRESS x.x.x.x`
`SSH  USERNAME 'admin'`  `SSH PORT 0000` SSH AUTH  method password and `USER PASSWORD 0000`

currently, I am getting

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 127.0.0.1:xxxx: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

How to define SSH details in my `settings.py` file ???

Answer (score 0):

You can use Paramiko library for this.

it works pretty well.

here is good explanation of how to set it up.

https://hackersandslackers.com/automate-ssh-scp-python-paramiko/

don't hesitate to forward encountering problems once you do it.